# Is there a way to check if an object is undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have read a [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7426#issuecomment-196500331) issue that says there was no consensus on using `T?` as a way to see if a type is `null | undefined` which is a shame. I also read recommendations not to use null so I've set `"strictNullChecks": true,` in my tsconfig but with the code below TS shows me that `blah` can be of type `Blah` or `undefined` therefore I have to check if it's undefined before using a property.  Is there a idiomatic way to do this check, I know `T?` doesnt exist (wish it did) but is there some other built in way of doing it without having to write something in a helper class in all my projects?

```
interface Blah {
    middleInitial?: string;
    age?: number;
}

class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string, public blah?: Blah) {
        var middleInitial = blah == undefined ? "" : blah.middleInitial;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same way you check if its undefined in JS:  `typeof blah === "undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write the line in the constructor like that:

```
var middleInitial = (blah && blah.middleInitial) || "";
```